# Why it is showing sigsev error on spoj..??

Tags: c, runtime-error, segmentation-fault

```
## Here is the link to the question http://www.spoj.com/problems/SBANK/
## i am getting sigsev error on the spoj.i have used mergesort to sort the account number ##


#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
void merge(int,int,int);
char a[10000][33];
```

**Merge function to sort the array. As account number is more than 18 digit i have used string library function to compare the account numbers stored in string **

```
 void mergesort(int low,int high)
{   int mid;

if(high>low)
{
     mid=(high+low)/2;
    mergesort(low,mid);
    mergesort(mid+1,high);
    merge(low,mid,high);

}
else
    return;
}
void  merge(int low,int mid,int high)
{
int i=low;
int j=mid+1;
int k=0;

char temp[10000][33];

while(i<=mid&&j<=high)
{
    if(strcmp(a[i],a[j])<0)
    {


        strcpy(temp[k],a[i]);
        i++;

    }

    else
    {
       strcpy(temp[k],a[j]);
        j++;

    }
    k++;
}

while(i<=mid)
{
    strcpy(temp[k],a[i]);
    k++;
    i++;
}

while(j<=high)
{
   strcpy(temp[k],a[j]);
    k++;
    j++;
}
k=0;
    while(low<=high)
        {
            strcpy(a[low],temp[k]);
            low++;
            k++;
        }
}
```

> Main driving function
>
> In one of the internet banks thousands of operations are being performed every day. Since certain customers do business more actively than others, some of the bank accounts occur many times in the list of operations. Your task is to sort the bank account numbers in ascending order. If an account appears twice or more in the list, write the number of repetitions just after the account number. The format of accounts is as follows: 2 control digits, an 8-digit code of the bank, 16 digits identifying the owner (written in groups of four digits), for example (at the end of each line there is exactly one space):
>   30 10103538 2222 1233 6160 0142

Banks are real-time institutions and they need FAST solutions. If you feel you can meet the challenge within a very stringent time limit, go ahead! A well designed sorting algorithm in a fast language is likely to succeed.

```
int main()
{

int t;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
    int i,n;
    int ch;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    getchar();



   for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    gets(a[i]);
  printf("\n");

    mergesort(0,n-1);

    int j=1;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(a[i],a[i+1])==0)
        {   j++;
           continue;
        }
        else
            {
        printf("%s %d\n",a[i],j);
        j=1;
        }
    }
     printf("%s %d\n",a[i],j);

}
return 0;

}

[Problem to sort bank accounts number of 26 digit][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of your fixed size arrays overflows if the strings are longer than 32 characters or there are more than 10000 of them.

An access to data at an index that wasn't properly initialized could also cause an out-of-bounds read.

Comment: While `mergesort()` is obviously recursive, unless I'm reading the code completely wrong, it doesn't appear that there will ever be more than one instance of `merge()` active at once (it appears to be a leaf function, outside of the calls to `str*()`), so recursive accumulation of large stack frames is probably not the issue. However, 330KB is still an insanely large stack frame... Also there are a lot of `<=` comparisons that make me highly suspicious of out-of-bounds array accesses...

Comment: @twalberg: Yes, you are right, `merge` isn't called recursively.

Comment: @twalberg Even using quicksort giving runtime error . Help please!

Comment: @user3135098 Asking us to debug your complete program is outside the scope of this site. Use a debugger or insert tracing code to narrow down where the issue is; then if you have a specific question about why something happens the way it does, feel free to ask.